# Try/Catch Failing Incorrectly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, try-catch

I'm trying to use Try/Catch to handle a potential failed connection to a database.  There's a Response.Redirect command in the Catch section.  Whenever the page loads it redirects as per the Catch section whether the code in the Try section fails or not.

If I comment out the Response.Redirect command in the Catch section the page loads just fine.  Similarly, if I replace the Response.Redirect command with code to populate a control on the page with the supposed error being trapped the Try section succeeds.  It's something about having Response.Redirect in the Catch section...

```
Private Sub Page_Load(Sender As Object, e As eventargs) Handles Me.Load

    Try
        Dim sqlcon As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SarcoidsConnectionString").ConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT PortalEnabled FROM [tlkSettings]", sqlcon)
        sqlcon.Open()
        Dim dbReader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If dbReader.HasRows Then
            While dbReader.Read()
                If dbReader("PortalEnabled") = True Then
                    Response.Redirect("~/SubmitWizard.aspx")
                Else
                    Response.Redirect("~/Maintenance.aspx")
                End If
            End While
        End If
        sqlcon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception 'Display Maintenance page if database cannot be connected to
        Response.Redirect("~/Maintenance.aspx")
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Try Response.Redirect("~/Maintenance.aspx", false)

Comment: The Catch part cannot be reached unless getting an error in the Try one. Confirm that Response.Redirect("~/Maintenance.aspx") is not written anywhere else in your code and that the given situation is actually not catched (perhaps you are expecting certain error, which does not happen; but a different one appears).

Comment: The line `If dbReader("PortalEnabled") = True Then` probably throws an exception. `dbReader("PortalEnabled")` returns an `object` and cannot be compare to true without first casting it to `boolean`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Response.Redirect()` without the second parameter of `False` will generate a `ThreadAbortException` because `.End()` is called on the `Response` object, so the following lines are the issue:

```
If dbReader("PortalEnabled") = True Then
    Response.Redirect("~/SubmitWizard.aspx")
Else
    Response.Redirect("~/Maintenance.aspx")
End If
```

Change it to this:

```
If dbReader("PortalEnabled") = True Then
    Response.Redirect("~/SubmitWizard.aspx", False)
Else
    Response.Redirect("~/Maintenance.aspx", False)
End If
```

The second parameter to `Redirect()` is the `endResponse` value, when setting it to `False` this tells the response to not call `.End()` and thus does not generate a `ThreadAbortException`.

Per MSDN documentation:

> When you use this method in a page handler to terminate a request for one page and start a new request for another page, set endResponse to false and then call the CompleteRequest method. If you specify true for the endResponse parameter, this method calls the End method for the original request, which throws a ThreadAbortException exception when it completes. This exception has a detrimental effect on Web application performance, which is why passing false for the endResponse parameter is recommended. For more information, see the End method.

Read [HttpResponse.Redirect Method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, this makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Problem is related to the other Response.Redirect Statements:

```
If dbReader("PortalEnabled") = True Then
    Response.Redirect("~/SubmitWizard.aspx")
Else
    Response.Redirect("~/Maintenance.aspx")
End If
```

Response.Redirect always throws a ThreadAbortException. This is caught in your exception handler as it catches any exception. Either you substitute the Reponse.Redirect calls or you add a handler the catches ThreadAbortExceptions:

```
Try
    '...
Catch threadAbort As ThreadAbortException
    Throw
Catch ex As Exception
    '...
End Try
```

By the way: you should add some Using statements to close the connection and free other objects reliably.

Comment: You can control whether or not `Response.Redirect()` throws a `ThreadAbortException` by using the overloaded version which accepts a `Boolean` parameter for `endResponse`; `True` is the default, which causes the thread aborting condition you speak of. See my answer for more information.

Comment: Yes, you are right. On the other hand, if I already know that I want to redirect and do nothing else (except setting resources free) the exception is not too bad IMHO.

Comment: Does the sqlcon.Close() statement not close the connection satisfactorily?

Comment: Only if it is run; it an exception is thrown before, it won't execute. Therefore, I suggest to use a Using block (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh(v=vs.90).aspx) like Using sqlCon As New SqlConnection(...) followed by End Using just when you don't need it anymore.